How do I run Selenium-Python automated scripts through Jenkins on remote machine
I developed a framework with Selenium-python and now its time to execute all the scripts through Jenkins. Its running absolutely fine on local machine through Jenkins but to run automated script through Jenkins on remote/cloud machine, what kind of code/file need to be share with Devops team so they can run automated script on cloud through Jenkins. Any help will be highly appreciated.
